# Does angular13 app-shell support i18n build?

Tags: angular, internationalization, app-shell

just pwa, the ngsw.json:

```json
{
  "urls": [
      "/en-US/favicon.ico",
      "/en-US/index.html",
      "/en-US/main.5acdb24ff94375e5.js",
      "/en-US/manifest.webmanifest",
      "/en-US/polyfills.1fcf5bb524b41b13.js",
      "/en-US/runtime.39739f775675b274.js",
      "/en-US/styles.01b68997c00690dc.css"
  ],
}
```

add app-shell, the ngsw.json:

```json
{
  "urls": [
      "/favicon.ico",
      "/index.html",
      "/main.5acdb24ff94375e5.js",
      "/manifest.webmanifest",
      "/polyfills.1fcf5bb524b41b13.js",
      "/runtime.39739f775675b274.js",
      "/styles.01b68997c00690dc.css"
  ],
}
```

angular13 app-shell does not support i18n build right now?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is, please check this website for more
[click here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. You have to create an absolutely static template for `app-shell` because it loads before any other module. Even use inline `css`. see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/app-shell).

> Application shell is a way to render a portion of your application using a route at build time. It can improve the user experience by quickly launching a **static rendered page** (a skeleton common to all pages) while the browser downloads the full client version and switches to it automatically after the code loads.
>
> This gives users a meaningful first paint of your application that appears quickly because the browser can render the HTML and CSS without the need to initialize any JavaScript.